# In Xcode using Swift, how can one make a press on, release off, button?

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

How can one program a button that executes a set of commands when it is pressed and then stops the execution when it is released in Xcode? For example: when the button is pressed a light is turned on and when it is released the light turns off.

Comment: searching for UIButton in youtube I found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lksW12megQg). Searching for "Xcode storyboard" I found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Inn2K-V3NFI). There are thousands of Swift related videos/tutorials online. You just have to google them

Comment: Attach events for touchDown and touchUpInside on the button putting the code you want executed in the correct event respectively.

Answer (score 3):

It is pretty simple using IBActions/Targets:

```
let btn = UIButton()
btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.on(_:)), for: .touchDown)
btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.off(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

You could also use storyboards to give the same effect

```
@IBAction func on(_ sender: UIButton?) -> Void {}
@IBAction func off(_ sender: UIButton?) -> Void {}
```

Then when connecting your actions, connect `on()` for your onTouchDown and `off()` for your onTouchUpInside, etc..